# Return variables in a for loop from imported script function

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have two .py files (test1.py & test2.py)

Now I want in a loop to run test1.py and to import a function from test2.py, let it execute and return the values back to test1.py

test1.py:

```
from test2 import fun

for i in range(5):

    % do stuff

    fun(times, data)

    xarr[i] = x
    yarr[i] = y
```

test2.py:

```
def fun(times,data):

    % do stuff

    return [x,y]
```

It works to execute, but the variables xarr[i] and yarr[i] are not generated

Comment: Provide us with more code pls.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python how to call a function", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: x,y = fun(times, data)

Answer (score 2):

```
from test2 import fun

for i in range(5):

    % do stuff

    var = fun(times, data)

    xarr[i] = var[0]
    yarr[i] = var[1]
```